# retrieve the result of an ajax request as a variable

Tags: ajax, variables

How can I get the result of my ajax post into a variable:

```
function decode_original(hshdecode) {   
    var decode_original = 'decode=1&hashvalue=kjh4k5hq35l&hashkey=12345';
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8",
            url: 'decode_function.php',
            data: decode_original,
            cache: false,
            success: function(return_value) {
                    var decoded_value = return_value;
                    console.log("Decoded Value:" +decoded_value);   
                    return decoded_value;
            },
            error: function(data){
                    return data;
            }
        });     
}
```

The above actually gets the return value successfully, but I am unable to pass the result into a variable:

```
var decode_value = decode_original(encoded_value);
        alert(decode_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

use **responseText** like :

```
success: function(return_value) {
                    var decoded_value = return_value.responseText;
                    console.log("Decoded Value:" +decoded_value);   
                    return decoded_value;
            }
```

Comment: that doesnt work either. the text I need is displayed in the log as decoded_value. responseText doesnt display a value at all?

Comment: What value your server returning and what are expecting int log ?

Comment: the log shows the response from the decode_function.php, its just a number. console.log("Decoded Value:" +decoded_value) does have the value, but "return decoded_value" clearly doesnt return the value.

Comment: return_value object contains the header and response both . 1) just return the number from your php file . 2) alert(return_value);alert(return_value.responseText); you will get the difference

Comment: I think what's happening here is that the request returns after the function responds with a result. The result only appears in the log after the var decode_value = decode_original(encoded_value); var decode_value is therefore undefined. Another thing is that the function is being called during an each() 'loop' over a class of elements so I need the result per element.

Comment: I don't think the above example is possible :-)

Comment: Sorry for late response ... Are you getting this issue now. Let me know I will solve this .